# Glassfish bundle in unexpected state exception

Tags: glassfish-3, redhat, java-6

So, basicly:

there is a standalone (no cluster) new installation of Glassfish 3.1.2 on RHEL 6.2 and Java 6 without any deployed applications (really new installation).

I started default domain domain1 on the server for the first time and stopped it without anything done between start/stop.

When i start the domain again, t get following error:

```
    Waiting for domain1 to start ...Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
04.06.2011 18:27:47 BundleProvisioner update
INFO: Updated bundle 1 from /home/glassfisfusr/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar
04.06.2011 18:27:47 BundleProvisioner update
INFO: Updated bundle 2 from /home/glassfisfusr/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/endorsed/javax.annotation.jar
04.06.2011 18:27:47 BundleProvisioner update
INFO: Updated bundle 3 from /home/glassfisfusr/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar
04.06.2011 18:27:47 BundleProvisioner update

skipped 

04.06.2011 18:27:49 BundleProvisioner update
INFO: Updated bundle 319 from /home/glassfisfusr/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/autostart/osgi-ee-resources.jar
04.06.2011 18:27:49 OSGiFrameworkLauncher launchOSGiFrameWork
INFO: Updating system bundle
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bundle in unexpected state.
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:164)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bundle in unexpected state.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.acquireBundleLock(Felix.java:4856)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.start(Felix.java:809)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:157)
        ... 9 more
Error stopping framework: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher$1.run(GlassFishMain.java:203)
```

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at this bugreport: http://java.net/jira/browse/WSIT-1642?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3Aactivity-stream-issue-tab

The following does help:

```
rm -rf $GF_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/osgi-cache/
```

Comment: The suggested command worked for me and cleared the problem. Thanks! rm -rf $GF_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/osgi-cache/

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally we also get (ubuntu 12.04, glassfish 3.0.1, Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)

```
[#|2012-06-13T19:17:02.763+0000|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|ERROR: Error locking file:/opt/glassfish/glassfish/modules/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.jar (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bundle in unexpected state.)|#]

[#|2012-06-13T19:17:02.764+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bundle in unexpected state.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.acquireBundleLock(Felix.java:4474)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1049)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

|#]

Haven't found any solution, except that sometime completely removing (mv /installationpath/glassfish /tmp/.) and re-installing glassfish works. You may also want to delete/move .updatetool from glassfish runtime user home dir.

Answer (score 0):

Removing cache is not a good idea. 
Problem you are having is coming from your system time.
If you are using Linux based OS than you must synchronize your system with an NTP server before starting glassfish. 
run

```
service ntpd stop
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
service ntpd start
```

If that does not help, create file /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
and paste this in that file:

```
server 0.pool.ntp.org
server 1.pool.ntp.org
server 2.pool.ntp.org
server 3.pool.ntp.org
```

run 
    `service ntpd restart`

and you're done. You can start glassfish now..

Answer (score 0):

run cmd  with administrator 
asadmin start-domain